# mvn clean install compilation failure for JUnit 5

Tags: maven, junit-jupiter

I am running Junit 5 tests in 2 projects. In one project same set up is workign fine and tests are runwithout issue.

In the other project I am consistently getting below compilation error. The dependencies are added in PoM file and when run from eclipse, tests run without error. Just mvn clean install fails. I have looked at various posts for similar error but it did not solve my issue. Any leads will be really helpful. same pom file in other projects works perfectly fine.

```
Error:
     Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project junit5-sampletests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestDemoClass2.java:[3,29]     package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestBaseClass.java:[3,29] package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestBaseClass.java:[4,29] package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestDemoClass1.java:[3,29] package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestDemoClass3.java:[3,29] package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
  [ERROR] /E:/BestX/Workspace/junit5-sampletests/src/test/java/demoTest/TestDemoClass2.java:[7,10] cannot find symbol
```

Contents of my pom file:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-sampletests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>

                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/surefire-report.html</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Structure in Eclipse:

The test are very simple as of now as I am tryign to create and prorotype junit5 framwrok. One of teh test file is:

```
package demoTest;
```

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

/**

- @author ayesha
- 

*/
public class TestDemoClass3 extends TestBaseClass {

```
@Test
public void test5() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Test 1 from DemoClass 3 "  +Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Test

public void test6() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Test 2 from DemoClass 3 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

}
```

}

Comment: First follow conventions and don't redefine sourceDirectory unless you 100% know what you are doing... (usr default directory layout `src/main/java/<package>` production code.. `src/test/java/<packageName>` unit tests` etc.) Furthermore why do you define the `test-jar` goal of the `maven-jar-plugin`... Why using maven-dependency-plugin to copy??? into a lib directory?
apart from that your error is: `package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist `... which 
Define surefire/failsafe plugin with at least version 2.22.2 to support JUnit Jupiter 5.X also remove the explicit surefire-provider....

Comment: Also remove the whole configuration from your maven-surefire-plugin because if you follow conventions that is not needed apart from it is wrong... After all decide to use JUnit Jupiter or JUnit 4... also please show one of your tests in particular that one which fails to be compiled etc...

Comment: @khmarbaise: I edited pom as per your guidance. Copyign dependency into lib as I will be sign command line to trigger JUNIT 5 tests after storign all required dependecies for junit platform in lib. That works well in other set up though. Also added samle code. The error is still not gone after changing pom

Comment: `Copyign dependency into lib as I will be sign command line to trigger JUNIT 5 tests ...`? Can you explain that more in detail? simple example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/example-junitjupiter (The issue in your TestBaseClass.java). Using inheritance within unit tests is usually a bad idea...

Comment: @khmarbaise The paln is to execute Junit5 tests from command line using java command and platform runner. The jars needed for this command are in lib directory. I can skip that step and have jars one time copied to lib dir. But porblem sees to be somewhere else. I could run scripts with exactly same pom and set up for otehr project. I think it has something to do with project setting or something. But not able to nail down the cause. Looks more like a maven issue to me

Comment: Why? Why not using Maven for that?  Take a look at my example ... that works... so not a Maven issue it's an issue in your setup/project...

Comment: I copied your example PoM file and tried running the mvn clean install on that. Still it give  package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist error. I too feel its project setting issue. But cant get leads on how to resolve.

Comment: I found the issue with my pom file. I had somehow  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> tag added to pom file. Removing this , worked well. Somehow, this tag never caught my attention . Issue resolved with this. Thanks @khmarbaise for your swift responses.

Comment: As I wrote at the beginning: `First follow conventions and don't redefine sourceDirectory unless `...

Answer (score 0):

src tag was added to the pom file. Removing this , worked well.  This was the cause of issue. After removign this tag the issue was resolved

Comment: The post doesn't explain where/how to add this "src tag" -> no help.